# How to bind DataGrid in my situation using mvvm (ObservableCollection inside ObservableCollection)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am under a situation where  i have ObservableCollection of "tablegenerateModel" class which further contains ObservableCollection of "column_Data" class,and this "column_Data" class contains 3 UI elements  which have to  be binded to DataGrid containing three columns.  **You can copy paste my code if you want,I have written all classes and xaml for you to verify my code**
So my Model.cs is as follows :

```
  public class tablegenerateModel {

    public ObservableCollection < column_Data > Column_data_List {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int NumberOfColumns {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private ICommand _CreatColumnCommand; //THIS IS THE BUTTON EVENT GENERATED WHEN USER PRESS AN INTEGER VALUE IN "NumberOfColumns" AND PRESS "Create" button. So the "Column_data_List" will repeat that many times the value user entered
    ViewModel vm;
    public ICommand CreatColumnCommand {
        get {
            if (_CreatColumnCommand == null) {
                _CreatColumnCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => vm = new ViewModel(this)
                );
            }
            return _CreatColumnCommand;
        }
    }
}
public class column_Data {
    public string Column_Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My View Model is:

```
   public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private ObservableCollection < tablegenerateModel > _lb_GlobalList;
    private ObservableCollection < column_Data > _Column_data_List;

    public ObservableCollection < tablegenerateModel > lb_GlobalList {
        get {
            return _lb_GlobalList;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _lb_GlobalList) {
                _lb_GlobalList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("lb_GlobalList");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection < column_Data > Column_data_List {
        get {
            return _Column_data_List;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _Column_data_List) {
                _Column_data_List = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Column_data_List");
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand

    private bool _canExecute;
    public ViewModel() {
        _canExecute = true;
        lb_GlobalList = new ObservableCollection < tablegenerateModel > ();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            //Add To it data here
        }
    }

    public ViewModel(tablegenerateModel tablegenerateModels) //IT WILL BE CALLED WHEN BUTTON WILL BE CLICKED (see tablegenerateModel class ICommand for it)
        {
            Column_data_List = new ObservableCollection < column_Data > ();
            for (int i = 1; i < tablegenerateModels.NumberOfColumns; i++) { //Add data here
            }
            MessageBox.Show("The NumberOfColumns value is:" + tablegenerateModels.NumberOfColumns);
        }

}
}
```

And View is :

```
 <Window x:Class="PyXgen.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:vM="clr-namespace:PyXgen" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vM:ViewModel></vM:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Name="ButtonsContainer">


        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding lb_GlobalList}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="0,30,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Grid Margin="0,2">


                                            Grid.Row="0" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0" Name="fname4"/>
                                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="70" Content="Create" Command="{Binding CreatColumnCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Margin="0,2" Grid.Row="5">
                                    <DataGrid x:Name="gvSelectedCourses" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Column_data_List , Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="450">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column Name" Binding="{Binding  ,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" />
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The button click to "_CreatColumnCommand" (in tableGenerateModel class)  will invoke the ViewModel contructor passing "this" object to get the entered integer value to repeat DataGrid rows number of times the entered integer value (this integer value is entered in "NumberOfColumns" textbox of same class)

Now problem is how to bind the "_Column_data_List" such that it will Add and Update the DataGrid's row (by the integer value which user have entered in textbox.

Currently when i enter the integer value in textbox and click the "create" button then ViewModel contructor is called with MessageBox popup

```
 MessageBox.Show("The NumberOfColumns value is:" + tablegenerateModels.NumberOfColumns);
```

How to bind this "_Column_data_List" to  such that it will add or update the DataGrid's row (by the intger value which user have entered in textbox, in the snapshot above).

**Could some one help me pleaseeeeeeeeeeeee ?**

Answer (score 2):

Update your code as below. You have binded observable collection within the tablegeneratedModel but you are updating one that is on ViewModel.

```
public ViewModel(tablegenerateModel tablegenerateModels) //IT WILL BE CALLED WHEN BUTTON WILL BE CLICKED (see tablegenerateModel class ICommand for it)
        {
            tablegenerateModels.Column_data_List = new ObservableCollection<column_Data>();
            for (int i = 1; i < tablegenerateModels.NumberOfColumns; i++)
            {
                Column_data_List.Add(lb_col = new column_Data()
                {
                    Column_Name = "ColumnName" + i,
                    Data_Size = i,
                    Data_types = "Double" + i
                });
            }           
            MessageBox.Show("The NumberOfColumns value is:" + tablegenerateModels.NumberOfColumns);
        }
```

Comment: No thats not the problem.. i have found the problem Myself. But thanks for your ideas and time :)

Answer (score 0):

'CreatColumnCommand' is misspellt, but consistently so, so that is not your problem. But your 'CreatColumnCommand` is not in the viewmodel, but in the model. Is that the problem?

Comment: CreatColumnCommand is in Model.. Because it is supposed to be in Model as i click enter a intger value .Lets say i done 3 in my snap shot. and then click "create" button.. This button is called succesfully as the messagebox is popup in ViewModel "public ViewModel(tablegenerateModel tablegenerateModels) ". but it is my DataGrid is suppose to be have 3 rows because i have a for-loop which Add some data in loop to the ObservabelCollection of "Column_data_List". This data is not added in my grid. as u can see in snapshot. Thats the problem. You can copy and paste my all code and verify it.

Comment: Ah, so not about binding the command. And your new viewmodel is made, but mainwindow does not reflect the new vm? Is there anything telling your view that the vm has changed? Isn't the view still looking at the old vm?

Answer (score 0):

In the given situation i must have ObservableCollection inside ObservableCollection but if you see my ViewModel, I am trying to add to the Column_data_List in ViewModel,Whereas i should do it in Model itself (as view will not handle to both lb_GlobalList and Column_data_List). I done it and it could work for me.